How to clear a signal from noise in GNU Radio
I am trying to detect a signal from a drone using an HackRF in GNU Radio. I want to implement something like seeing its signature when my drone is far away and its signal is covered by noise. I know i have to use something with FFT but i dont really know how. If you can help me i will be happy. Thank you!

Your FFT doesn't help you at all if noise and signal have the same spectral properties; so, no, it's not that easy.
You need to define a signal model, according to which you can find something that separates your signal from your noise (which follows a noise model; often in microwave communications as done by consumer drones, that's a simple additive white noise model).
Only after describing what your signal is can you start looking into how to improve the SNR.
